# Deploying WAR on Amazons Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have created a simple "HelloWorld" servlet in an Eclipse project.  I built it into a WAR,  deployed it in my Tomcat 7.0 local server and a simple request  `localhost/HelloWorld/sayhello`  prints "HELLO"
No rocket science there.
So following AWS documentation on how to deploy a WAR
I go to Beanstalk management console and see the message "You do not have any AWS Elastic Beanstalk applications launched"  so I click on Tomcat 7 -> start,  and upload my WAR.  After the upload completes and AWS tells me it is now running I click on "view running version" and it opens the link 
`default-environment-zhqv8mwsqw.elasticbeanstalk.com`
I then tried `default-environment-zhqv8mwsqw.elasticbeanstalk.com/HelloWorld/sayhello` 
but I get a `404`.
Have I missed something or is there anything I can check?  How do I explicitly tell AWS to use a 32 Bit JVM?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

It should be default-environment-zhqv8mwsqw.elasticbeanstalk.com I then tried default-environment-zhqv8mwsqw.elasticbeanstalk.com/sayhello

On your local you use context path in url but in EBS it deployed at root. so need to put context.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on this and just had to remove the context.

Comment: This answer is exactly one line, explaining the issue concisely and to the point. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is not a line or two.  I have several tutorials on my own website, among them one on how to deploy a war to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.  It is specific for Grails, but works for any war.  Here is a link that will take you to the specific tutorial on my website: [how to deploy a war to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk](http://www.databaseapplications.com.au/elastic_beanstalk.jsp)  Please note that this link will take you away from stackoverflow and to my website.  You can right click the link and say "open in a new tab" to keep stackoverflow open.